# Instagram embed video says "watch on instagram" but not playing on website

Tags: next.js, video, instagram, embed

I'm building a website with Nextjs in which I am trying to show Instagram video post. For this I am using 'Embed' option of Instagram. I am copying the embed code from Instagram and pasting in my html.

In my website some Instagram Videos play within web page. See screenshot below.

[image]

We can see play option is there. And when I click on play button, video starts playing.

But some videos do not play in web page and show option "Watch on Instagram". See below screenshot

[image]

When I click on play button, Instagram website gets open and videos play there.

I want to play the videos within my web page and not on Instagram.

I tried to find the solution on Google. I tried different options but could not get a solution.

[image]

Comment: Do you actually have anything that is testable? Like a simple demo page showing **only** 2 embeds (where one works, the other doesn't)... Else maybe just share 2 links that we can test by pasting into our own iframes to see your problem in action. Most likely the answer is you cannot do anything about it. This could be because of a copyright issue (where such videos cannot be distributed outside of Instagram).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I figured out that the reason some instagram embeds are working and some force you to go to the instagram page was to do with music copyright on the videos. If it's original audio you can use it on you website. Hope this helps if anyone has the same issue.